# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false after login successfully mvc core 3.0 with web api

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

this is the image of the problem.

[image]

my login function in the API

```
        public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] LoginDto model)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.Email || x.UserName == model.Email);
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            var IsAuthenticate = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Email == model.Email);
                return await GenerateJwtToken(model.Email, appUser);
            }

            return BadRequest("INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT");
        }
```

my login function in MVC with consume API
_client.LoginAsync() is a static function to consume API for login

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                await _client.LoginAsync<LoginDto>(new Uri(_appSettings.WebApiBaseUrl + "Account/Login"), model);
                ApplicationManager.SetMessageToUser("تم تسجيل الدخول بمجاح");
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
                return Redirect("/" + returnUrl);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        ApplicationManager.SetMessageToUser("تأكد من اسم المستخدم وكلمة المرور");

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

_client.LoginAsync() is a function to consume api for login

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync<T>(Uri requestUrl, T content)
        {
            addHeaders();
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl.ToString(), CreateHttpContent<T>(content));
            string st = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return (string)data;
        }
```

my configuration for services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    });
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")); 
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
       opt.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ECommerceWebDb;Integrated Security=True"));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

    // configure jwt authentication
    var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();


    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default",
         pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
         name: "areas", "areas",
         pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

I complicated with this error
I think this is everything if you want more to help me please tell me.

Comment: I don't know if this solves anything, but you should remove the line `string st = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` from LoginAsync.

Comment: thank you, this did not solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solve

if you face the same problem JWT does not support cookies with tokens together so you must remove

```
x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

from    `services.AddAuthentication`

```
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {

    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;

        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
```

when you need to authorize any action by token you can use this attribute

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

to any actions.

when you need to authorize any action by cookie you need to add

```
[Authorize]
```

Answer (score 1):

SignIn persists the given information for future requests, it does not set `HttpContext.User` on the current one.So
`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be true on the subsequent requests

Refer to

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/cutting-edge-cookies-claims-and-authentication-in-asp-net-core#foundation-of-aspnet-authentication

> n ASP.NET, user authentication involves the use of cookies. Any users that attempt to visit a private page are redirected to a login page if they don't carry a valid authentication cookie. The login page, after having verified provided creden-tials, emits the cookie, which then travels with any subsequent requests from that user through the same browser until it expires. This is the same basic workflow you might know from past versions of ASP.NET. In ASP.NET Core, it only looks different because of the different middleware and the different configuration of the runtime environment.